# How to generate sound on Android TextView Hover

Tags: android, textview

I want to generate sound on android Text View..
Like in my app when someone hover on A. it sound AA.. When hover on B.. It should B. Like SO On..
Any Recommendations?

Comment: what do you mean by hover? do you mean press and hold?

Comment: I Mean like when mouse is placed on TextView or touch on textView A.. it should sound A..

Comment: Search Google But Could Not Find ANy Solution So Post Here..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Touch Listener on your text view and a media player like this. This code is approximate and untested.

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    Uri soundA = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) { 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                     mPlayer.setDataSource(this, soundA);
                     mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                     mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                     mPlayer.prepare();
                     mPlayer.start();
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                }

            }
        }
    });

}
```